# PC won't load past bios

Tags: boot, upgrade

Can't load PC past bios menu.

Twice now I've upgraded my PC to 16.04 and both times the problem has occurred. Once I restart after the upgrade my computer will not boot past the BIOS POST. I'm able to open the BIOS menu and boot from the CD or USB drive however, am unable to boot from hard drive. To get my PC running after the first go I had to reinstall Ubuntu desktop twice, then install Ubuntu Studio, as intended.

What could be causing such a significant system failure?

Comment: If the computer cuts out before an OS has even had an attempt to load, it's not the OS. This looks like a nasty coincidence more than anything.

Comment: You're able to get the BIOS screen to appear on the video display, yes? EXACTLY what happens when you exit the BIOS? Does the screen then throw the error "no video input"? Is this a desktop machine, or a laptop? Cheers, Al

Comment: Heynnema, yes, it saves and exits, then goes to the no video input message and my monitor goes to sleep. It is a desktop. I'm also noticing the CD drive doesn't seem to be fully spinning up after 3 or 4 tries of booting. It's has now begun starting and stopping, making a jump feeling almost. I'm trying a USB load next. I'll keep you posted.

Comment: Power off the machine and unplug it from the AC. Open the desktop and remove (hopefully it's not soldered in) the quarter-size battery that you'll find on the motherboard. Note which way it goes in. Push in and hold the main power button for 5-10 seconds. Let the machine sit for 10-15 minutes. Reinstall the battery. Turn on the machine and immediately go into the BIOS. Set the BIOS back to defaults (usually a menu choice to do this). You may have to reset the BIOS clock. Now see if you can boot completely. Report back. Cheers, Al

Comment: Tried that already, no luck, past effectively resetting the BIOS.

Comment: The BIOS is not my PRIMARY reason for suggesting what I did. It's the `power manager` on the motherboard. You should also disconnect all external devices... USB, etc. So if you can, try it my way, and maybe you'll get lucky. Last thought... do you have a series of beeps when you power on... like an error code? I've got a bizillion years of experience at this. Keep us posted. Cheers, Al

Comment: I've tried to boot from CD which isn't working as wel as USB, which loads the YUMI menu, allows me to select the distro I want to launch, then craps out like before, but does keep the video output activated.

Comment: I'm presently downloading a different distro of Ubuntu desktop to try, but it seems rather hopeless. At this point I'm just hoping I can figure out what happened and what is broken that I need to replace, mostly because I just built it maybe 6 months ago.

Comment: If you would just **try** my suggestion(s)... Cheers, Al

Comment: Sorry, same result. Tried it twice more and left it set for a good 30 min the third go.

Comment: I disconnected all drives while it was running but crapped out and when it was off. Disconnecting while somewhat running fixed the issue. As soon as I rebooted, it booted up just fine. Though it also showed duplicates of all my drives, so I'm not sure exactly what happened.

Comment: So the problem is partially fixed. I can boot from CD and USB, as well as HD. Unfortunately I can't boot anything directly, only by booting through the BIOS menu.

Answer (score -1):

Don't update to Ubuntu 16.04. I was able to isolate the system failure version 16.04. I was unable to load a clean distro at all, from a 16.04 version. I am also unable to operate the PC after an upgrade of any Ubuntu distro to 16.04.

I can work the PC perfectly on multiple distros at 14.04. Fortunately I had quite a few older distros laying around on my laptop and in CDs. It is unclear what is causing the failure, the CPU, Mobo, the combo.

My specs - 
ASUS: Mobo: A88xm-E
CPU:  AMD A6-7400K Radeon R5

Comment: In your second paragraph, did you mean 14.04?